# Apache mod_proxy AH00927 messages

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-proxy

I was hoping someone could help me with my apache2 and mod_proxy. I have the following setup:

- Python web server 1 (HTTP)
- Python web server 2 (HTTP)
- Python web server n (HTTP)

Apache (2.4.7) with mod_proxy with multiple VirtualHosts like so:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName ws1.domain.com
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:1234/
  ProxyPassRevers / http:/localhost:1234/
  ....
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName ws2.domain.com
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
  ProxyPassRevers / http:/localhost:8080/
  ....
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName wsn.domain.com
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:5678/
  ProxyPassRevers / http:/localhost:5678/
  ....
</VirtualHost>
```

I was recently looking at my `apache-error.log` file and it's flooded with the following messages:

```
[Fri Dec 11 21:26:43.989831 2015] [proxy:debug] [pid 23813] proxy_util.c(1734): AH00927: initializing worker http://localhost:1234/folder local
[Fri Dec 11 21:26:43.989846 2015] [proxy:debug] [pid 23813] proxy_util.c(1785): AH00931: initialized single connection worker in child 23813 for (localhost)
```

Should I be worried? What do these messages mean and why are they in the error log if they're marked as `[proxy:debug]`?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Should I be worried?

No

> What do these messages mean

Exactly what they say

> and why are they in the error log if they're marked as [proxy:debug]?

The `proxy:debug` is a LogLevel and the LogLevel directive only acts upon the ErrorLog. We can therefore deduce that this was a design decision.